# change text in the second column in the ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I want to change the text color of the second column, all those that are less than 4.0 that turn red.

my viewHolder code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderDatos holder, int position) {

    holder.punto.setText(puntoNotaList.get(position).getPunto());
    holder.nota.setText(puntoNotaList.get(position).getNota());

    }
```

Comment: You can use `setTextColor()` and add if statement when your less than 4.0.

Comment: and how would the code be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setTextColor()` in an if statement and when the value is less than 4.0 you set `Color.RED` otherwise `Color.BLUE` I think in your case.

In this example we change nota.

**Example**

```
...
if (Double.parseDouble(puntoNotaList.get(position).getNota()) < 4) {
    holder.nota.setTextColor(Color.RED);
} else {
    holder.nota.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
}
...
```

Comment: That's the problem I have: What to put in / * Value you want compare * /?

Comment: I don't know because I need more code for this. And what is punto and nota wich one you want change color.

Answer (score 0):

AdapterDatos.java

```
public class AdapterDatos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterDatos.ViewHolderDatos>{

Context context;
ArrayList<PuntoNota> puntoNotaList;

public AdapterDatos(Context context, ArrayList<PuntoNota> puntoNotaList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.puntoNotaList = puntoNotaList;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolderDatos onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list,parent,false);
    ViewHolderDatos viewHolder = new ViewHolderDatos(itemView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderDatos holder, int position) {

    holder.punto.setText(puntoNotaList.get(position).getPunto());
    holder.nota.setText(puntoNotaList.get(position).getNota());


    if((position % 2) == 0)
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFeceff1);

    else
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFffffff);


    }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return puntoNotaList.size();
}


public class ViewHolderDatos extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView punto, nota;

    public ViewHolderDatos(View item) {
        super(item);
        punto = item.findViewById(R.id.idPunto);
        nota = item.findViewById(R.id.idNota);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Next time edit your code. Don't put it on answer this can mix us.

Comment: I sent you adapterData, if you need another files or codes I will send you immediately, and thanks for helping me.

Comment: And wich one you want to change color punto or nota

Comment: I want to change the nota.